# Summarize first column same field

Tags: apache-2.2, bash, scripting, grep, sed

I have some datas with URL's and used network data. I made a custom file with these data's and i stuck last one step.
What i have now:

```
sevroland.api.url.com   488
www.logstach.url.com    42725
localhost   2
goldchipshop43.api.url.com  568
www.extremepoints.in    25918
sevroland.api.url.com   488
sevroland.api.url.com   488
sevroland.api.url.com   19538
vipmarkethu.api.url.com 63747
www.lakas.us    571
www.mybrands.eu 24527
www.mrpotencianusika.de 729
mozaik.wellis.us    125157
xiaomi.url.com  2
www.netshop.eu  2
www.kerekpor.sk 32956
mozaik.wellis.us    39986
www.controlaltdel.ro    82
localhost   27285
replicamodel.api.url.com    3673
replicamodel.api.url.com    2
www.designmark.sk   38249
localhost   2
```

What i want:

```
sevroland.api.url.com   46920
www.logstach.url.com    42725
localhost   27289
goldchipshop43.api.url.com  568
www.extremepoints.in    25918
vipmarkethu.api.url.com 63747
www.lakas.us    571
www.mybrands.eu 24527
www.mrpotencianusika.de 729
mozaik.wellis.us    125157
xiaomi.url.com  2
www.netshop.eu  2
www.kerekpor.sk 32956
mozaik.wellis.us    39986
www.controlaltdel.ro    82
replicamodel.api.url.com    3675
www.designmark.sk   38249
```

So the first column is the url, the second is the network usage. From the source file i want to add up same url's network usage numbers.
Thank you very much any help, feedback!

Comment: See Andrey's answer to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242946/using-awk-to-sum-the-values-of-a-column-based-on-the-values-of-another-column). You won't need the `-F '|'` part of course, but other than that, it's perfect for your needs.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, it is work's fine! Thank you!